# UPI Payment Gateway using Android Deep Link

Tags: android, xamarin.android, upi

Is there any working sample to integrate UPI payment gateway using Android Deep Link. I went through NPCI specifications and implemented it with no success. Transaction is not getting completed.

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Console.WriteLine("Request Code:" + requestCode);
    }

    private void RunUPI(string MobileNo)
    {
        var UPIUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("upi://pay?pa=xxx@xxxx&pn=xxxxxx&mc=null&tid=null&tr=test101&tn=This%20is%20test%20payment&am=10&mam=null&cu=INR&url=null");
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionView);
        intent.SetData(UPIUri);
        var activities = PackageManager.QueryIntentActivities(intent, PackageInfoFlags.MatchDefaultOnly);
        var isIntentSafe = activities.Count > 0;
        if (true == isIntentSafe)
        {
            var chooser = Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Pay With");
            chooser.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            // Verify the intent will resolve to at least one activity
            if (chooser.ResolveActivity(PackageManager) != null)
            {
                txnUPIRequestCode = 0;
                StartActivityForResult(chooser, txnUPIRequestCode);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

The problem in your case is not related to `UPI` but how Android manages `Activity` results and `Intent`s.

You **cannot** use the [`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) if the caller (in this case your `Activity`) is requesting a result from the activity being launched (the *UPI PSP* in this case). [[source]](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

So a simple solution would be to simply create the `Uri` and launch the `Intent` without the flag. In java that would look like:

```
private void launchUPI(){
  // look below for a reference to these parameters
  Uri uri = Uri.parse("upi://pay").buildUpon()
    .appendQueryParameter("pa", "xxx@xxxxx")
    .appendQueryParameter("pn", "XYZXYZ")
    .appendQueryParameter("tn", "Pay for in-app purchase")
    .appendQueryParameter("am", "20")
    .appendQueryParameter("cu", "INR")
    .build();

  Intent upiPayIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  upiPayIntent.setData(uri);

  Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(upiPayIntent, "Pay with");

  if(null != chooser.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())) {
    Log.d(TAG, "UPI Payment resolved to activity");
    startActivityForResult(chooser, REQ_UPIPAYMENT);
  } else {
    Log.d(TAG, "No activity found to handle UPI Payment");
  }
}

@Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  if(REQ_UPIPAYMENT == requestCode){
    if(RESULT_OK == resultCode){
      Log.d(TAG, "UPI Payment successfull");
    } else {
      Log.d(TAG, "UPI Payment failed");
    }
  }
}
```

As far the *request parameters* are concerned, following is a simple reference that I got from the [UPI DeepLinking Specificication page](https://www.npci.org.in/sites/default/files/UPI%20Linking%20Specs_ver%201.6.pdf).

- **`pa`**: UPI Virtual address of the *payee* (the one who receives the payment)
- **`pn`**: Name of the *payee*. Can be name of merchant or store.
- **`tn`**: Transaction note. A simple description of the transaction, like, payment for in-app items, bill payments, etc.
- **`am`**: Monetary amount of transaction in decimal format.
- **`cu`**: Currency used in the transaction. Currently only INR is supported.

Using the above parameters, you can create a payment request **static mode** to the *PSP* app (apps like PayTM or bank applications).

To create a payment request in **dynamic mode**, you also need to add the following:

- **`tr`**: Transaction reference. Your internal reference to the transaction in your system.

---

#### UPDATE 1

As the OP mentioned in the comments, to get back the response from the *PSP* app, like, transaction id, etc. we can use the `Intent` passed in the `onActivityResult()` when `RESULT_OK == resultCode`.

```
@Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  if(REQ_UPIPAYMENT == requestCode){
    if(RESULT_OK == resultCode){
      Log.d(TAG, "UPI Payment successfull");
      String transId = data.getStringExtra("response");
    } else {
      Log.d(TAG, "UPI Payment failed");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It works.Thank you so much. How can I read the transaction response parameter such as txnId, responseCode, txnRef(from NPCI specification)?

Comment: Got it String var pspResonse = intent.getStringExtra("response");

Comment:  cool! Thanks for sharing. I'll update the answers for future readers

Comment: Hi Guys...
May I know where to declare REQ_UPIPAYMENT  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can the list of all UPI apps on the device and use any app to initiate the transaction.

**This is the function that you can use to fetch all the UPI apps.**

```
private fun upiApps(context: Context): MutableList<PaymentUpiOption> {

    val upiOptions = mutableListOf<PaymentUpiOption>()

    // Set Parameters for UPI
    val payUri = Uri.Builder()

    payUri.scheme("upi").authority("pay")
    payUri.appendQueryParameter("pa", "")
    payUri.appendQueryParameter("pn", "")
    payUri.appendQueryParameter("tid", "")
    payUri.appendQueryParameter("mc", "")
    payUri.appendQueryParameter("tr", "")
    payUri.appendQueryParameter("tn", "")
    payUri.appendQueryParameter("am", "")
    payUri.appendQueryParameter("cu", "")

    val paymentIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    paymentIntent.data = payUri.build()

    val appList = context.packageManager.queryIntentActivities(paymentIntent, 0)
    for (i in appList) {
        // this is a custom model class
        val paymentUpiOption = PaymentUpiOption(
            i.loadLabel(context.packageManager).toString(),
            i.activityInfo.packageName,
            i.loadIcon(context.packageManager),
            "upiTxn",
            "UPI"
        )
        upiOptions.add(paymentUpiOption)
    }
    return upiOptions
}
```