# Launching payments app like Phonepay via intent Android

Tags: android, android-intent, upi

There are similar questions on StackOverflow but none of them worked for me.

List of Questions

1. [UPI Payment Gateway using Android Deep Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49041760/9640177)
2. [UPI App Deep linking using Intent - inconsistent and buggy behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44985944/9640177)

Somehow I managed to open Uri starting with `upi://pay` using `startActivity(new Intent(ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse(upi_string)));` However when I try to use createChooser, no app is detected which can handle UPI payments.

How do I create a chooser for UPI apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]
I am using flutter and in my app when i  tap on google pay or any upi app icon
a url launcher is launched
the function is:

```
_launchgooglepay() async {
  const url =
      'upi://pay?pa=kechamadavipul@okhdfcbank&pn=Payee Name&tn=Payment Message&cu=INR';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

The url

```
upi://pay?pa=kechamadavipul@okhdfcbank&pn=Payee Name&tn=Payment
```